# Python3.7 rasterio library cant open jp2

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, gdal, rasterio

I want to open a jp2 image from sentinel2 but when I read the image

```
band = rasterio.open(imagetest, driver= 'JP2OpenJPEG')
```

I get the next error

```
'D:\DataStorage\00_sentinel_data\L1C_T29SQB_A013147_20171228T111919\IMG_DATA\T29SQB_20171228T111451_B02.jp2' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I have installed GDAL with OSGeo4W and I can see the driver when I use the gdalinfo --formats command

```
JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
```

The only thing that I see that could be the problem is that when I see the gdal formats that I have using python, the JP2OpenJPEG driver does not exist.

```
from osgeo import gdal
for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()):
    drv = gdal.GetDriver(i)
    if drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DCAP_RASTER):
        print(drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_LONGNAME), drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_EXTENSIONS))
```

Any ideas about what is happening??

Python version: 3.7
Gdal version: 2.3.3
Rasterio version: 1.0.21

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It looks like this is a problem in Anaconda's GDAL. Here is one way to fix the problem:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/250837/149170

Unfortunately, upgrading/downgrading the base package in Anaconda did not work for me.

I was finding that installing the package "fiona" with pip was downgrading gdal for me. I finally fixed the issue of downgrading gdal by installing fiona using conda:

```
conda install fiona
```