# can't open jp2 (from sentinel) with python rasterio,gdal

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to open the jp2 rasters products in python as raster, without success when we use the "raterio" and "gdal" packages.
I get this errors:

```
RasterioIOError: 'b4.jp2' not recognized as a supported file format.
RuntimeError: `b4.jp2' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I do manage to open them as a regular matrix with "glymur" package but then i lose the geo data.

If someone know other pachage to open jp2 as raster i would be happy to know!

I tried to follow this answer: [Python3.7 rasterio library cant open jp2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611197/python3-7-rasterio-library-cant-open-jp2) 
installed fiona by conda
or: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250833/gdal-missing-jp2-driver-files-how-to-install-them/250837#250837
and tried to install :`conda create -n mynewenv -c conda-forge gdal rasterio`
but i still get the same errors.

```
b4 = rasterio.open('b4.jp2')
b4 = rasterio.open('b4.jp2', driver= 'JP2OpenJPEG')
```

Comment: can you open it using `gdal.Open()`

Comment: also what does `rasterio.gdal_version()` return?

Comment: no i tried, didn't work,  gdal version: '2.3.3'

Comment: how about `gdal.VersionInfo()`

Comment: gdal.VersionInfo() gives '2030300'

Comment: I wish i knew the answer to this, but i rememver I had a really hard time getting rasterio to install properly.  I am using gdal version `2040100`.

Comment: according to [this comment](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1790#issuecomment-537297127), you could try installing rasterio and linking it to you system gdal `pip install numpy; pip install -I --no-binary rasterio rasterio`, but that sounds iike a can of worms to me.

Comment: i'll try this, in a couple of days and let you know.. thanks!

Comment: Hi, that also doesn't work.. do you have other solutions?

Comment: I would think about using `gdal warp` to convert `jp2` to `GTiff`.  Other than that all you cand do is uninstall everything geospatial, and reinstall specific a specific version of rasterio that supports `.jp2` driver.

Comment: I just installed rasterio on google colab and apparently `rasterio.__version__` =  1.1.0 with `rasterio.gdal_version()`` = `2.4.2` supports the `JP2OpenJPEG` driver.

Comment: you can check if the specific rasterio version supports the `.jp2` using `rio`.   `rio env --formats`

Answer (score 5):

This is quite similar to what you have tried, but this procedure just worked for me. Note: I am specifying I want a python 3.7 environment.  From the anaconda prompt:

```
conda create --name testing python=3.7
conda activate testing
conda install -c conda-forge gdal rasterio
```

Verified correct install:

```
(testing) C:\Users\dan>python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 22:01:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rasterio
>>> import gdal
>>> gdal.VersionInfo()
'3000100'
>>> rasterio.gdal_version()
'3.0.1'
```

And check to make sure `.jp2` driver is supported.  From the anaconda prompt:

```
rio env --formats
```

which returns a long list with the entries:

```
JML: OpenJUMP JML
JP2OpenJPEG: JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
JPEG: JPEG JFIF
```

And here is the export from `conda env export`:

```
name: testing
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - affine=2.3.0=py_0
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - boost-cpp=1.70.0=h6a4c333_2
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hfa6e2cd_1
  - ca-certificates=2019.9.11=hecc5488_0
  - certifi=2019.9.11=py37_0
  - cfitsio=3.470=hfa6e2cd_2
  - click=7.0=py_0
  - click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
  - cligj=0.5.0=py_0
  - curl=7.65.3=h4496350_0
  - expat=2.2.5=he025d50_1004
  - freetype=2.10.0=h563cfd7_1
  - freexl=1.0.5=hd288d7e_1002
  - gdal=3.0.1=py37h2fee047_10
  - geos=3.7.2=he025d50_2
  - geotiff=1.5.1=h6e819c3_4
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=hb01d8f6_1002
  - glib=2.58.3=hc0c2ac7_1002
  - hdf4=4.2.13=hf8e6fe8_1002
  - hdf5=1.10.5=nompi_ha405e13_1104
  - icu=64.2=he025d50_1
  - jpeg=9c=hfa6e2cd_1001
  - kealib=1.4.10=hf7dc31f_1005
  - krb5=1.16.3=hdd46e55_1001
  - libblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libcblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libcurl=7.65.3=h4496350_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=h6538335_1006
  - libgdal=3.0.1=h2491c49_10
  - libiconv=1.15=hfa6e2cd_1005
  - libkml=1.3.0=h4ece8bf_1010
  - liblapack=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libnetcdf=4.7.1=nompi_h8d74e2a_101
  - libpng=1.6.37=h7602738_0
  - libpq=11.5=hb0bdaea_1
  - libspatialite=4.3.0a=hee5a54d_1031
  - libssh2=1.8.2=h642c060_2
  - libtiff=4.0.10=h6512ee2_1003
  - libxml2=2.9.10=h9ce36c8_0
  - lz4-c=1.8.3=he025d50_1001
  - numpy=1.17.3=py37hc71023c_0
  - openjpeg=2.3.1=hb24c2e3_1
  - openssl=1.1.1c=hfa6e2cd_0
  - pcre=8.43=h6538335_0
  - poppler=0.67.0=h92819f6_7
  - poppler-data=0.4.9=1
  - postgresql=11.5=h06f7779_1
  - proj=6.2.0=ha7a8c7b_1
  - pyparsing=2.4.2=py_0
  - python=3.7.3=h510b542_1
  - rasterio=1.1.0=py37h2617b1b_0
  - snuggs=1.4.7=py_0
  - tbb=2018.0.5=he980bc4_0
  - tiledb=1.6.2=h30b6f50_1
  - tk=8.6.9=hfa6e2cd_1003
  - xerces-c=3.2.2=h6538335_1004
  - xz=5.2.4=h2fa13f4_1001
  - zlib=1.2.11=h2fa13f4_1006
  - zstd=1.4.0=hd8a0e53_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.4=245
  - m2w64-expat=2.1.1=2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gettext=0.19.7=2
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libiconv=1.14=6
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - m2w64-xz=5.2.2=2
  - mkl=2019.4=245
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - pip=19.3.1=py37_0
  - setuptools=41.6.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.30.1=he774522_0
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
  - vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_0
  - wheel=0.33.6=py37_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py37_0
prefix: C:\Anaconda2\envs\testing
```

proof it works:

```
(testing) C:\Users\RDCRLDDH>python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 15:18:51) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rasterio
>>> ds = rasterio.open(r"C:\Users\RDCRLDDH\Desktop\T36QVM_20191023T082009_B01.jp2")
>>> ds.crs
CRS.from_epsg(32636)
>>> ds.read(1)
array([[2372, 2344, 2312, ..., 1423, 1406, 1481],
       [2326, 2292, 2279, ..., 1492, 1462, 1495],
       [2317, 2271, 2261, ..., 1529, 1517, 1511],
       ...,
       [1958, 1946, 1947, ..., 1697, 1734, 1730],
       [1960, 1960, 1967, ..., 1714, 1758, 1721],
       [1959, 1957, 1960, ..., 1769, 1752, 1701]], dtype=uint16)
>>> ds.transform
Affine(60.0, 0.0, 399960.0,
       0.0, -60.0, 2700000.0)
>>>
```

From spyder, you can check to see where spyder is running from using

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You should see something like:

```
C:\Anaconda2\envs\testing\pythonw.exe
```

The installation directory `C:\Anaconda2\` will depend on where you have anaconda installed to, But the latter part `envs\testing\pythonw.exe` should be the same.

Comment: Hi, installed as mentioned here, at prompt i get for rio env --formats the jp2 entries (which is good i didn't get that before). and the same as yours for conda env export. but at the spyder editor, gdal.VersionInfo() gives '2030300' , rasterio.gdal_version() gives '2.3.3'. however i still can't open jp2 with rasterio.open..

Comment: I tried couple of jp2 files with both rasterio and gdal open, with no successes.. I agree that's frustrating!

Comment: Hi, maybe there is another solution?

Comment: ooh, I just re-read your first comment.  Install spyder into the environment `testing`.  `pip install spyder`.  Then run spyder from that environment.

Comment: Hi, I pip install spyder again, after conda activate testing, thats what you mean? rasterio.gdal_version() still gives '2.3.3'..

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If you installed following my directions, you should see the `rasterio.gdal_version() == '3.0.1'`.  What if you open a python interpreter in the command prompt as I have shown above?

Comment: @asafalon updated to show how to check which environment spyder is running from

Comment: Hi! if i use the prompt as  interpreter from prompt i get rasterio.gdal_version() == '3.0.2', but if i use spyder and define in "preferences" python interpreter from "testing " env i.e:  C:\Users\shilo\Anaconda3\envs\testing\python.exe, i cannot even import rasterio or gdal (in spyder)

Comment: yeah, the python path manager won't change how spyder is connecting to the python executable.  All that does is allow you to import packages that aren't in the `site-packages` folder.  If you have installed spyder in `testing`, you can find the executable at: `C:\Users\shilo\Anaconda3\envs\testing\Scripts\spyder.exe`

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Comment: I've never gotten the [modular approach](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach) to work.  I just use the [naive appoach](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-naive-approach)

Comment: if this helped you, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi, i tried execute C:\Users\shilo\Anaconda3\envs\testing\Scripts\spyder.exe but spyder doesn't run from it..Is there other way to run rasterio and gdal from based env, and make them upgrade?

Comment: yes, it opens a prompt window for a sec, but doesn't run the spyder

Comment: what a pain,  how did you install spyder?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only have one instance of spyder open at a time.  Make sure you dont have spyder running from base.

Comment: Hi, when i'm trying to execute spyder from windows (i.e double click on spyder.exe which locate in C:\Users\shilo\Anaconda3\envs\testing\Scripts\spyder.exe ) i get propmpt window that disappear after 1 sec, i made sure no other spyder running. when i'm trying to execute from command prompt, i get: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'"

Comment: I installed spyder at testing env, by pip

Comment: Try using `conda-forge` :  `conda install -c conda-forge spyder`

Comment: still the same.. sorry

Comment: if you are getting module not found errors, something is wrong with the spyder install.  Try creating a new envrionment and installing spyder in there.